# Есть ли в PHPStorm "Панель элементов" как в Visual Studio?

Tags: phpstorm

Есть ли в PHPStorm "Панель элементов" как в Visual Studio (с которой вставляются шаблонные коды html, css, js, комментарии)?

В PHPStorm, везде искал, не нашёл.

Comment: Можете описать как это в vs реализовано?

Comment: Панель кодов типа <img> <a href>, при клике это появляется в коде.
В панель кодов можно добавлять свои коды.